# react testing library and export const Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I've pretty much built my entire app using this format to export my components

```
export const PageLayout = (props) => {
    const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated();

    return <div>{isAuthenticated ? <Main /> : <Landing />}</div>;
};
```

but when testing with react test library, I have to change the format of my export or else the component won't render at all in test

```
const PageLayout = (props) => {
    const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated();

    return <div>{isAuthenticated ? <Main /> : <Landing />}</div>;
};

export default PageLayout
```

If I have to go with second export, then I'll have to change all of the imports in my project and I'd really prefer not to do that so is there a way to use react test library without changing my import / exports?

example code snippet:

```
describe("Login page", () => {
    it("renders login button", () => {
        render(<PageLayout />);

        const buttonText = screen.getByText(/sign in/i, { exact: false });
        expect(buttonText).toBeVisible();
    });
```

Comment: How are you importing? The style of export/import shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can do something like this:

```js
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import {PageLayout} from './PageLayout';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  render(<PageLayout />);
  const linkElement = screen.getByText(/learn react/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Comment: Nope. I get a type error if I don't change the format of the export of the components.

Comment: Could you share the testing code?

Comment: added the code snippet in the main post.

if I export my PageLayout like I did in the first code snippet, then I get an error. If I export it using the second code snippet, then it works fine and the test case succeeds

Comment: By any chance, useIsAuthenticated does an async process?

Comment: @DanielLee *What error???*

Comment: Btw, you're missing: `})` at the end of the describe suite

Comment: the error that I'm getting is: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string ( for  built-in components) or a class / function (for  composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. I want to emphasize, when I export my components like I do in the second example, the test suites pass but if it's exported like the first example, then it fails

Comment: Could you share the snippet of how you are importing the PageLayout component?

Comment: Definitely the issue has something to do with that way you're exporting and importing the component.

**wrong way:**
`export const  App = () => {...`
`import {App2} from './App';`

**Right way:**
`export const  App = () => {...`
`import {App} from './App';`